# Why m I receiving a 'The method doesn't override an inherited method' warning , over a function called in InitState()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, I am receiving this warning over a function that I called in InitState , the main aim of the function was to run and ask the permission to access location of the user. Could anyone please let me know why m I getting this warning and is there a better way to write the following code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class _UserLocationState extends State<UserLocation> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    permissionGranted();
  }

  Location location = new Location();
  PermissionStatus? _allowed;
  @override
  
  Future<void> permissionGranted() async {
    final PermissionStatus permissionRequested;
    _allowed = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_allowed == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      print('Permission has been denied');
      permissionRequested = await location.requestPermission();
      setState(() {
        _allowed = permissionRequested;
      });
    } else
      setState(() {
        _allowed = PermissionStatus.granted;
      });
  }

  //final _userLocation = await location.getLocation();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used @override just above the 'permissionGranted()' method due to which you are getting 'The method doesn't override an inherited method' as 'permissionGranted()' is user defined one. You should use @override above 'initstate()'. Or, just copy it -

```
class _UserLocationState extends State<UserLocation> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    permissionGranted();
  }

  Location location = new Location();
  PermissionStatus? _allowed;
  
  Future<void> permissionGranted() async {
    final PermissionStatus permissionRequested;
    _allowed = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_allowed == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      print('Permission has been denied');
      permissionRequested = await location.requestPermission();
      setState(() {
        _allowed = permissionRequested;
      });
    } else
      setState(() {
        _allowed = PermissionStatus.granted;
      });
  }

  //final _userLocation = await location.getLocation();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted it! thanks a lot. This one solved it.

Answer (score 1):

`initState` should be used as an overridden method. So, you're missing `@override`.

```
@override //add this
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    permissionGranted();
  }
```